# Cómo ajusto el siguiente cálculo de fechas

Tags: symfony2

Tengo una función en una `Entity`, la misma calcula la edad gestacional a partir de la fecha de la última menstruación de la embarazada, y tomando como argumento una determinada fecha.

Esta es la función:

```
public function getEdadGestacional(\DateTime $apartirDeFecha = null){
   $diff = 0;
   if(is_null($apartirDeFecha)){
       $hoy = new \DateTime('today');
       $diff = $hoy->diff($this->getFechaUltimaMenstruacion());
   }else{
       $tmp= new \DateTime($apartirDeFecha->format('Y-m-d'));
       $diff = $tmp->diff($this->getFechaUltimaMenstruacion());
   }

return round($diff->format('%a')/7,1);
}
```

La cuestión es que cuando uso la función sin pasarle el argumento fecha, me devuelve un resultado, y cuando le paso como argumento, por ejemplo, la fecha actual para comparar, me devuelve otro resultado que difere en 0.1.

Ampliando:
La `fechaUltimaMenstruacion`, es una tributo de la entidad `Embarazada`, y se inserta al registrar una nueva embarazada, es de tipo `date`, por tanto no hay problemas con el componente hora.

Ahora bien, puntualmente cuando se registra un nuevo nacimiento para la embarazada, es ahí donde está el problema:

```
$embarazada->setEdadGestacionalAlParir($embarazada->getEdadGestacional($nuevoNacimiento->getFechaNacimiento()));
```

la propiedad `getFechaNacimiento` de la entidad `Nacimiento` tambien es de tipo `date`.

Cuando muestro en la vista los nacimientos me doy cuenta que para una embarazada que registré un nacimiento en la fecha actual, por ejemplo, la edad gestacional del nacimiento difiere de la edad gestacional que tenía cuando ella aun estaba embarazada, para esa misma fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Si la diferencia es **tan** baja puede ser debido al redondeo. El manejo interno de floats es [muy complejo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947/how-is-floating-point-stored-when-does-it-matter) y, de manera interna, cada lenguaje lo implementa como estima oportuno.

Un ejemplo de esto es el cálculo `0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` que es 0 pero, en PHP, obtenemos el resultado `5.5511151231258E-17`. Casi 0, pero no es 0 matemáticamente hablando.

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
function getEdadGestacional(\DateTime $apartirDeFecha = null) {
    $diff = 0;
    if (is_null($apartirDeFecha)) {
        $hoy = new \DateTime('today');
        $diff = $hoy->diff(new \DateTime('2016-01-05'));
    } else {
        $tmp = new \DateTime($apartirDeFecha->format('Y-m-d'));
        $diff = $tmp->diff(new \DateTime('2016-01-05'));
   }

   return round($diff->format('%a') / 7, 1);
}

print_r(getEdadGestacional() . "\r\n");
print_r(getEdadGestacional(new \DateTime('today')) . "\r\n");
```

Con este código consigo resultados iguales. Lo único que veo que puede variar con el tuyo es en la propiedad `fechaUltimaMenstruacion`. ¿Por qué no pruebas a poner a fuego una fecha concreta y ver si sigue pasando? Si obtienes los mismos resultados, el problema puede estar ahí.

Comment: ufff; peroooo, es mas o menos correcta la manera en que trato de manejar esa fecha ?. Qué sucede con esto, la edad gestacional de la embarzada debe almacenarse al momento de registrar un nacimiento, y me está sucediendo que al pasarle como fecha a la función que describí anteriormente, la fecha de nacimiento del bebé y que coincida o no con la fecha actual, pues se almacena un valor de edad gestacional diferente al que muestro en la vista para la fecha actual (si coincidiera con la fecha de nacimiento del bebé) de la embarzada antes de registrarle el nacimiento.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta.